# converting video file byte[],or Buffer into bitmaps of Android,getting images from videofile

Tags: android, bitmap, video-streaming, buffer, video-encoding

I am trying to represent images from that video file in Android controls.
I loaded video file in byte[] , also in other types like Buffer , ByteBuffer and Bitmap,I used all the functions available in Bitmap and Bitmap factory class but unable to get the images to be represented in android image button.
Can any one tell the Idea of getting images from above mentioned data types .
Any other study which you can recommend is welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to get a certain frame or thumbnail?

Comment: I am trying to get frame , thumbnail I already did , I want to get all the images from a video file in a way assignable to android image controls/imagebutton

Comment: I think there is no way to do that with android sdk. I think You need to write some native code using the ndk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it worked , I recommend all the readers to use FFMPEG using ndk and get all the frames the require . lot of sample projects there on git